# Elements from a text file not being added to the array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to add an Entry object to an array of Entries which consists of a Surname, Initial and Extention number. The first word on the line is the surname etc. however when I print the array using System.out.print(Arrays.toString(entries)); it doesn't print the array or it is empty.

Entry class

```
public class Entry {

    private String surname, initial, extension;

    public Entry() {

    }

    // shadowing
    public Entry(String line) {

        String[] lines = line.split("\t");
        this.surname = lines[0];
        this.initial = lines[1];
        this.extension = lines[2];


    }

    public void setSurname(String sur) {
        this.surname = sur;

    }

    public void setInitial(String ini) {
        this.initial = ini;
    }

    public void setExtention(String ext) {
        this.extension = ext;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public String getInitial() {
        return initial;
    }

    public String getExtension() {
        return extension;
    }

}
```

Array directory class

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayDirectory implements Directory {

    Entry[] entries = new Entry[0];
    int lines = 0;

    public ArrayDirectory() {

        try {
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("directory.txt"));

            Scanner lCounter = new Scanner(new FileReader("directory.txt"));

            while (lCounter.hasNext()) {
                lCounter.nextLine();
                lines++;
            }

            entries = new Entry[lines];

            for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
                addEntry(inFile.nextLine());
            }

        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public void addEntry(String l) {
        Entry newEntry = new Entry(l);

        int i = 0;

        while(entries[i] != null) i++;
    }

    public void printTable(){

        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(entries));
    }




}
```

Comment: Why are you using two scanners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding anything to your array:

```
 public void addEntry(String l) {
    Entry newEntry = new Entry(l);

    int i = 0;

    while(entries[i] != null) i++;
  }
```

You are missing an eventual `entries[i] = newEntry;`. Of course, once your array is full you'll get an exception with this code. You must ensure `i` doesn't grow larger than `entries.size -1`.

Consider using a list instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Entry` class need to override the `toString()` method. It is this method that Arrays.toString() will use and unless you implement your own version it will fall back to the default one from `java.lang.Object` which is not very human friendly.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s. %s", this.initial, this.surname);
}
```

You might be better off using a more flexible storage type too so you do not have to read through the file twice. An `ArrayList` would be appropriate and you can convert it to an array trivially after you have finished adding new entries to it.

How big is your file? Maybe a BufferedReader would be a better choice?

```
File file = new File("directory.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>()
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    entries.add(new Entry(line));
}
br.close();
```

Edit: You are not actually adding your Entry objects to the array. You should change this section:

```
entries = new Entry[lines];
for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
    addEntry(inFile.nextLine());
}
```

and this method:

```
public void addEntry(String l) {
    Entry newEntry = new Entry(l);
    int i = 0;
    while(entries[i] != null) i++;
}
```

You could add `entries[i] = newEntry;` just after that final while loop but it is a very poor way to do it. You are iterating through the whole array every time you add a new item. I'd suggest the `ArrayList` method I describe above.